# Cluster-autoscaler not triggering scale-up on Daemonset deployment

Tags: kubernetes

I deployed the Datadog agent using the [Datadog Helm chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/datadog) which deploys a `Daemonset` in Kubernetes. However when checking the state of the Daemonset I saw it was not creating all pods:

```sh
NAME                    DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR   AGE
datadog-agent-datadog   5         2         2       2            2           <none>          1h
```

When describing the `Daemonset` to figure out what was going wrong I saw it did not have enough resources:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                From                  Message
  ----     ------            ----               ----                  -------
  Warning  FailedPlacement   42s (x6 over 42s)  daemonset-controller  failed to place pod on "ip-10-0-1-124.eu-west-1.compute.internal": Node didn't have enough resource: cpu, requested: 200, used: 1810, capacity: 2000
  Warning  FailedPlacement   42s (x6 over 42s)  daemonset-controller  failed to place pod on "<ip>": Node didn't have enough resource: cpu, requested: 200, used: 1810, capacity: 2000
  Warning  FailedPlacement   42s (x5 over 42s)  daemonset-controller  failed to place pod on "<ip>": Node didn't have enough resource: cpu, requested: 200, used: 1860, capacity: 2000
  Warning  FailedPlacement   42s (x7 over 42s)  daemonset-controller  failed to place pod on "<ip>": Node didn't have enough resource: cpu, requested: 200, used: 1860, capacity: 2000
  Normal   SuccessfulCreate  42s                daemonset-controller  Created pod: datadog-agent-7b2kp
```

However, I have the [Cluster-autoscaler](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/cluster-autoscaler) installed in the cluster and configured properly (It does trigger on regular `Pod` deployments that do not have enough resources to schedule), but it does not seem to trigger on the `Daemonset`:

```
I0424 14:14:48.545689       1 static_autoscaler.go:273] No schedulable pods
I0424 14:14:48.545700       1 static_autoscaler.go:280] No unschedulable pods
```

The AutoScalingGroup has enough nodes left:

[image]

Did I miss something in the configuration of the Cluster-autoscaler? What can I do to make sure it triggers on `Daemonset` resources as well?

Edit:
Describe of the Daemonset

```
Name:           datadog-agent
Selector:       app=datadog-agent
Node-Selector:  <none>
Labels:         app=datadog-agent
                chart=datadog-1.27.2
                heritage=Tiller
                release=datadog-agent
Annotations:    deprecated.daemonset.template.generation: 1
Desired Number of Nodes Scheduled: 5
Current Number of Nodes Scheduled: 2
Number of Nodes Scheduled with Up-to-date Pods: 2
Number of Nodes Scheduled with Available Pods: 2
Number of Nodes Misscheduled: 0
Pods Status:  2 Running / 0 Waiting / 0 Succeeded / 0 Failed
Pod Template:
  Labels:           app=datadog-agent
  Annotations:      checksum/autoconf-config: 38e0b9de817f645c4bec37c0d4a3e58baecccb040f5718dc069a72c7385a0bed
                    checksum/checksd-config: 38e0b9de817f645c4bec37c0d4a3e58baecccb040f5718dc069a72c7385a0bed
                    checksum/confd-config: 38e0b9de817f645c4bec37c0d4a3e58baecccb040f5718dc069a72c7385a0bed
  Service Account:  datadog-agent
  Containers:
   datadog:
    Image:      datadog/agent:6.10.1
    Port:       8125/UDP
    Host Port:  0/UDP
    Limits:
      cpu:     200m
      memory:  256Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:     200m
      memory:  256Mi
    Liveness:  http-get http://:5555/health delay=15s timeout=5s period=15s #success=1 #failure=6
    Environment:
      DD_API_KEY:                  <set to the key 'api-key' in secret 'datadog-secret'>  Optional: false
      DD_LOG_LEVEL:                INFO
      KUBERNETES:                  yes
      DD_KUBERNETES_KUBELET_HOST:   (v1:status.hostIP)
      DD_HEALTH_PORT:              5555
    Mounts:
      /host/proc from procdir (ro)
      /host/sys/fs/cgroup from cgroups (ro)
      /var/run/docker.sock from runtimesocket (ro)
      /var/run/s6 from s6-run (rw)
  Volumes:
   runtimesocket:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /var/run/docker.sock
    HostPathType:  
   procdir:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /proc
    HostPathType:  
   cgroups:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /sys/fs/cgroup
    HostPathType:  
   s6-run:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:     
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                 From                  Message
  ----     ------            ----                ----                  -------
  Warning  FailedPlacement   33m (x6 over 33m)   daemonset-controller  failed to place pod on "ip-10-0-2-144.eu-west-1.compute.internal": Node didn't have enough resource: cpu, requested: 200, used: 1810, capacity: 2000
  Normal   SuccessfulCreate  33m                 daemonset-controller  Created pod: datadog-agent-7b2kp
  Warning  FailedPlacement   16m (x25 over 33m)  daemonset-controller  failed to place pod on "ip-10-0-1-124.eu-west-1.compute.internal": Node didn't have enough resource: cpu, requested: 200, used: 1810, capacity: 2000
  Warning  FailedPlacement   16m (x25 over 33m)  daemonset-controller  failed to place pod on "ip-10-0-2-174.eu-west-1.compute.internal": Node didn't have enough resource: cpu, requested: 200, used: 1860, capacity: 2000
  Warning  FailedPlacement   16m (x25 over 33m)  daemonset-controller  failed to place pod on "ip-10-0-3-250.eu-west-1.compute.internal": Node didn't have enough resource: cpu, requested: 200, used: 1860, capacity: 2000
```

Comment: Does cluster-autoscaler also change the maximum limit of the ASG? Maybe you've already hit that limit.

Comment: No I checked that already, the limit is 10 and it is at 5 nodes now.

Comment: Any activity in the ASG logs? Maybe it's snagging somewhere

Comment: Nothing interesting, only a succesfull deployment of an EC2 instance this morning.

Comment: Could you please `describe` the daemonset? There are [some annotations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/) that might affect it. Otherwise, there might be some labels or namespace issues and Datadog can't see it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add priorityClassName to point to a high priority PriorityClass to your DaemonSet. Kubernetes will then remove other pods in order to run the DaemonSet's pods. If that results in unschedulable pods, cluster-autoscaler should add a node to schedule them on.

See [the docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/pod-priority-preemption/) (Most examples based on that) (For some pre-1.14 versions, the apiVersion is likely a beta (1.11-1.13) or alpha version (1.8 - 1.10) instead)

```yaml
apiVersion: scheduling.k8s.io/v1
kind: PriorityClass
metadata:
  name: high-priority
value: 1000000
globalDefault: false
description: "High priority class for essential pods"
```

Apply it to your workload

```yaml
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: datadog-agent
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: datadog-agent
      name: datadog-agent
    spec:
      priorityClassName: high-priority
      serviceAccountName: datadog-agent
      containers:
      - image: datadog/agent:latest
############ Rest of template goes here
```

Comment: That is indeed a good alternative solution. In this case the daemonset was not actually high priority and it might cause downtime for other applications if we set it up like this. But this could indeed solve the issue if it is critical to run.

Comment: @Blokje5 The right way is probably to create several `PriorityClass`es for different parts of the system and apply the relevant ones. The monitoring agent might then knock off some non-critical pods like redundant web server instances. Another note: You really want to apply a `PriorityClass` to cluster autoscaler - I had a case where the ASG was manually rescaled accidentally and did not scale up due to autoscaler not being scheduled...

Comment: True that is indeed a valid point. If you apply proper configuration of PriorityClasses most likely it will just remove redundant copies.

Answer (score 2):

You should understand how cluster autoscaler works. It is responsible **only** for adding or removing nodes. It is not responsible for creating or destroying pods. So in your case cluster autoscaler is not doing anything because it's useless. Even if you add one more node - there will be still a requirement to run DaemonSet pods on nodes where is not enough CPU. That's why it is not adding nodes.

What you should do is to manually remove some pods from occupied nodes. Then it will be able to schedule DaemonSet pods.

Alternatively you can reduce CPU requests of Datadog to, for example, 100m or 50m. This should be enough to start those pods.

Comment: True, but with more nodes it would be able to rebalance the load, making sure there is enough space. Or am I misunderstanding what would happen on a scaleup?

Comment: Kubernetes will not rebalance the load unless you do it manually. Nothing in Kubernetes is about rebalancing the load in normal circumstances. Kubernetes starts moving pods only in case of resource pressure, such as lack of cpu and memory. In normal conditions Kubernetes tries to keep your pods where they are.